# Distributing Weight to the other KPI's if Value is "N/A"

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Data: Different KPI and Weight

```
   KPI     Weight 
   AAA       25
   BBB       25
   CCC       25
   DDD       25
```

The Values for KPI are 2, Full=25 and N/A = 0

What I need is If KPI_Value = "N/A" the weight should be distributed to the other KPI's keeping in mind the ProjectID and Date so it doesn't mix up the distribution. So for example,

```
ProjectID    KPI    KPI_Value    Date       Weight
   1        AAA      Full     24/02/2020     25 + 25/3
   1        BBB      Full     24/02/2020     25 + 25/3
  *1        CCC      N/A      24/02/2020     0*    <--------
   1        DDD      Full     24/02/2020     25 + 25/3

   2        AAA      Full     24/03/2020     25 + 50/2
  *2        BBB      N/A      24/03/2020     0*    <--------
   2        CCC      Full     24/03/2020     25 + 50/2
  *2        DDD      N/A      24/03/2020     0*    <--------
```

I'm Trying to Do this in Ms Access using a Query If you think this is not the best way Please Suggest a suitable way.

Comment: I expect this will require VBA. When you have specific code with issue, post question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience a query is the best approach in Access.  The forms and the reports are designed to be hooked up to queries and tables to minimize the code behind.  You can do this project with a query but in access you have two query based approaches.  Both approaches use calculated variables but the less portable approach is to use the built in Access and VBA functions.  The pure sql and hence more portable approach is to base the calculated variables on correlated sql subqueries.  In Access, and based on experience again, the access and vba functions approach is both far more robust and easier to implement so I will show that approach.

First I made some changes to and some assumptions about your data structure:

[image]

I let Access add a primary key called ProjectsTableID.  Every record needs a unique ID.  Then I assumed every variable was either a number or a string.  In particular notice that I refer to the value of KPI_Value as " 'NA' ".  That is how you refer to a string.  I also removed the / as I didn't want to deal with escaping it.  Also generalized weight as will be apparent.
Here is the query:
[image]

```
  CountofNA: DCount("KPI_Value","Projects","ProjectID = " & [ProjectID] & " AND KPI_Value =  'NA'")

SumofNAWeight: DSum("Weight","Projects","ProjectID = " & [ProjectID] & " AND KPI_Value =  'NA'")

NewWeight: IIf([KPI_Value]='NA',0,[Weight]+[SumofNAWeight]/[CountofNA])
```

Tweak the result for your datastructure:
[image]

Comment: I think I may have forgot to mention 1 more detail. The same ProjectID can repeat again but with a different date below. So after ProjectID 2 DDD, ProjectID 1 AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD repeats with a different date. So I tried Dcount without the date and it gave me the enitre count of 'NA' without taking date into account and when I tried DCOUNT with ProjectDate but it gave me zero. Any idea why?

Comment: ok just had to put it like ProjectDate = #"&[ProjectDate]&"#. So If the set of dates does not have a NA it doesn't show any value is it possible to make it show the exact value similarly the newweight also won't show if there is no NA

Comment: sorry about the no N/A bug.  One way to fix the bug is to add another If and only if function to new weight.  NewWeight: IIf([KPI_Value]='NA',0,IIf([CountofNA]=0,[Weight],[Weight]+[SumofNAWeight]/[CountofNA]))

Comment: Works absolutely great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my function `RoundSum` found on **GitHub**: [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round)

```vb
' Rounds a series of numbers so the sum of these matches the
' rounded sum of the unrounded values.
' Further, if a requested total is passed, the rounded values
' will be scaled, so the sum of these matches the rounded total.
' In cases where the sum of the rounded values doesn't match
' the rounded total, the rounded values will be adjusted where
' the applied error will be the relatively smallest.
'
' The series of values to round must be passed as an array.
' The data type can be any numeric data type, and values can have
' any value.
' Internally, the function uses Decimal to achieve the highest
' precision and Double when the values exceed the range of Decimal.
'
' The result is an array holding the rounded values, as well as
' (by reference) the rounded total.
'
' If non-numeric values are passed, an error is raised.
'
' Requires:
'   RoundMid
'
' 2018-03-26. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RoundSum( _
    ByVal Values As Variant, _
    Optional ByRef Total As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal NumDigitsAfterDecimal As Long) _
    As Variant
' <snip>
```

Too much code to post here, but the implementation is as simple as:

```vb
values = Array(25, 25, 0, 25)
sum = 4 * 25
weights = RoundSum(values, sum, 1)

result -> { 33.3, 33.3, 0, 33.4 }
```

Comment: Will check it out and reach out if I need any help.